# How is the rate of transcription influenced by temperature?

Tags: biochemistry, molecular-biology, dna, transcription, organic-chemistry

**How is the rate of transcription influenced by temperature?** More precisely, I am looking for an article who quantitatively measured the rate of transcription of an "average gene" and show how this rate is influenced by temperature.

On [this question](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/21138/influence-of-temperature-on-transcription-protein-binding-and-decay-rates) @Chris found [this article](http://genomebiology.com/2014/15/3/R45) where such measurement were performed but they were using some arbitrary unit (as it as been pointed out by @shigeta [here](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/21188/transcription-rate-expressed-in-microarray-per-hour)) that cannot be related to any comprehensive unit such as "mole of amino acid per hours" or something like that.

Comment: Also see [this answer](http://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/21258/how-does-temperature-influence-the-rate-of-protein-degradation/24218#24218)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your looking at transcription then your talking about RNA POLYMERASE.

And there are many variants. Here's a good Nature paper that discusses temperature and RNA Pol

http://www.nature.com/ncomms/journal/v1/n6/full/ncomms1076.html

And another:

http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/m/pubmed/12729734/

I couldn't get full access to this JBC paper but I think the answer would be clearly in here, prob worth a look

M. Chamberlin and J. Ring. Characterization of T7-specific ribonucleic acid polymerase. 1. General properties of the enzymatic reaction and the template specificity of the enzyme. J Biol Chem. 248: 2235-44 (1973)

Comment: Very nice. Thanks a lot. I found the answers I needed in the Chamberlin and Ring article. There's a similar question [here](http://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/21189/influence-of-temperature-on-protein-binding-and-decay-rates) if you feel you can answer it $\ddot \smile$